# how do i serialize list variable of type <boost::shared_ptr<void *>>

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I'm really not sure how do i serialize a list variable of type `boost::shared_ptr <void *>` inside a class or struct. Generally, i would go with same method that we generally use like

```
struct A
{
    std::list<boost::shared_ptr<void *>> mdb;
}

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &d,const unsigned int version)
{
      d & mdb;  // not sure that this would work
}
```

while compiling it does not give error but does not serialize at my end.

Comment: You have a `void*` inside your type. How do you serialize a `void*`?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this as written above really compiled. What do you mean by "serialize"? Are you sure what you really want is a shared pointer to  another pointer of type void?

Comment: @Pop - yes it is --  std::list<boost::shared_ptr<void *>> this only but how should i serialize this

Answer (score 0):

You don't. In all likelihood, the `void*` is

- a HANDLE (for some native API); you can serialize this only if the API has enough identifying information to reconstruct the handle on load
- a type pun for something else (this would be silly, just have the real type there, then)