# how to serialize list of type shared_ptr pointer type using boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

i'm trying to serialize class which has member variable of type like **std::list> lss**

```
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

struct SomeStruct
{
     int x;
     double y;

     private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version)
      {
         at & x; 
         at & y;
      }

};

class BuildTest
{

    std::list<boost::shared_ptr<SomeStruct *>> lss ; 
    std::string name;

    private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version)
      {
         at & lss;  // is this sufficient to serialize lss ?
         at & name;
      } 

}
```

i have added all required header files for boost serialization. There is similar question but with proper answer [how do i serialize list variable of type <boost::shared_ptr<void *>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457722/how-do-i-serialize-list-variable-of-type-boostshared-ptrvoid)

Comment: Please show the headers. Have you included 'boost/serialization/list.hpp', boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp' ?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking - added the all header files used in code.

Comment: did you write the serialisation code for SomeStruct?

Comment: Your code compiles fine, present a test case showing th issue.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
std::list<boost::shared_ptr<SomeStruct>> lss ;
```

Not `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<SomeStruct*>>`

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e22185779c1066c4)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

struct SomeStruct {
    int x;
    double y;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version) {
        at & x;
        at & y;
    }

};

class BuildTest {
  public:

    std::list<boost::shared_ptr<SomeStruct>> lss ;
    std::string name;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &at, const unsigned int version) {
        at & lss;  // is this sufficient to serialize lss ?
        at & name;
    }

};

int main() {
    BuildTest bt;
    bt.name = "Let's try this";
    bt.lss = { boost::make_shared<SomeStruct>(), boost::make_shared<SomeStruct>() };
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    oa << bt;
}
```

Comment: why we cannot use  std::list<boost::shared_ptr<SomeStruct*>>

Comment: @manu Why/how would you use SomeStruct**? How would you allocate this? I'd say it's either wasteful and useless or a very bad idea. (Possibly both).